# Cartesian to polar coordinate

Tags: analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates

I have this superellipse equation but how can I plot it? because I need the equation to be expressed as a function of x and y, like $x = \ldots$ and $y = \ldots$.

$(x-a)^n + (y-b)^n = r^n$

where $a$ and $b$ are the coordinates of the center, $r$ is the radius and $n$ an integer but how can I have $x = ...$ and $y = ...$, I mean dissociating x and y from the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us work as for $n=2$. There, we had - $$x=a+r\cos t$$ $$y=b+r\sin t$$
This was because we exploited the property $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t=1$, and as the terms $a$, $b$ were used to essentially re-center the ellipse to the origin.

Analogously, let us define - $$x=a+r\cos^c t$$ $$y=b+r\sin^d t$$
Thus, we get the relation $$\cos^{cn}t+\sin^{dn}t=1$$
This looks very similar to the identity mentioned above, and becomes identical if we take $c=\frac{2}{n}$, $d=\frac{2}{n}$. Thus, we get our parameterisation.

Comment: Ok but how do you get the last equation? Where does the n come from ?

Comment: From the $n$ in $(x-a)^n + (y-b)^n = r^n$